# Meteor: Variable is set randomly to NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, momentjs

I am trying to set new due dates for objects. Sometimes my code works and sometimes it doesn't.

The problem is that `newStep`is sometimes `NaN`. It should always be an integer.

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
Template.showCards.helpers({
    cards: function () {
        var end = moment().toDate();
        // Finding the next card to show by due date
        return Cards.findOne({deckId: this._id, due: {$lte: end}}, {sort: {due: -1}});
    },
    hard: function() {
        var step = Cards.findOne({_id: this._id}).step - 1;
        if (step < 0) { step = 0; }
        var days = Math.pow(2.5, step);
        return Math.round(days);
    },
    good: function() {
        var step = Cards.findOne({_id: this._id}).step + 1;
        if (step < 0) { step = 0; }
        var days = Math.pow(2.5, step);
        return Math.round(days);
    },
    easy: function() {
        var step = Cards.findOne({_id: this._id}).step + 2;
        if (step < 0) { step = 0; }
        var days = Math.pow(2.5, step);
        return Math.round(days);
    },
});

Template.showCards.events({
    // Show the answer
    'click .show-answer-btn': function (event) {
        $(event.target).prev().removeClass('hide');
        $(event.target).next().removeClass('hide');
        $(event.target).hide();
    },
    'click #difficulty button': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var step = Cards.findOne({_id: this._id}).step;
        var newStep = parseInt(step) + parseInt(event.target.value);
        if (newStep < 0) { newStep = 0; }
        var incBy = Math.pow(2.5, newStep);
        var today = moment();

        if (event.target.id == 'again-btn') {
            var newDue = moment(today).add(10, 'minutes').toDate();
        } else {
            var newDue = moment(today).add(incBy,'days').toDate();
            console.log(newDue);
        }

        Cards.update(
            this._id, {
                $set: {due: newDue, step: newStep}
            }
        );

        if (isNaN(newStep)) {
            console.log("ERROR");
        } else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }

        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="showCards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <p class="front">{{cards.front}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card hide">
        <div class="card-content">
            <p class="back">{{cards.back}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{#with cards}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary show-answer-btn">Show Answer</button>

    <div id="difficulty" class="btn-group hide" role="group">
        <button id="again-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="-1">
            Again
            <br>
            <small>10 min</small>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" value="-1">
            Hard
            <br>
            <small>{{hard}} days</small>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" value="1">
            Good
            <br>
            <small>{{good}} days</small>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" value="2">
            Easy
            <br>
            <small>{{easy}} days</small>
        </button>
    </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

My repo: https://github.com/mvaisanen/flashcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target` will refer to the element you clicked on. When the error occurs, you've clicked on the `<small>` element inside the `<button>` element. Use `event.currentTarget` instead, which will refer to the element matched by the selector (`#difficulty button` in your case).